5 distinct balls, I pick 2, Bob picks 3, probability that 1 of my ball is among the balls Bob picks
5 distinct balls, I pick 2 randomly, Bob picks 3 randomly, what is the probability that one of my ball is among the balls Bob picks?
I know how to do this problem with complementary counting $1 - \frac{1}{{5 \choose 2}} = \frac{9}{10}$. But i'd like to see what's wrong with my non-complementary counting approach:
Without loss of generality, suppose I pick ball 1 and 2.
case 1: when Bob picks both of my balls, Probability = $\frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{10}$
case 2: when Bob picks only one of my balls, Probability = $\frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{5}$
They don't add up to $\frac{9}{10}$....

It seems like you are only counting cases where the first ball picked by Bob (and possibly the second) are one of your picked ones. For example, you miss the case where Bob picks balls 3, 4, and only then 1.

Given the three balls of Bob, the probability of choosing none of those with two picks without replacement is $\frac{2}{5}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{10}$. So $1-\frac{1}{10}=\frac{9}{10}$.

Your complementary counting approach is correct.  As @Tzimmo pointed out in the comments, when you tried to count directly, you only considered sequences in which Bob selected one of the balls you selected first, then selected balls that you did not choose.  However, Bob does not have to pick one of your balls with his first selection.  A simpler approach is to consider which subsets of balls Bob selects.
Case 1: Bob selects both of the balls you selected and one of the three other balls, which can be done in $\binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{1}$ ways.
Case 2:  Bob selects exactly one of the two balls you selected and two of the other three balls, which can be done in $\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}$ ways.
Total:  Since these cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive and Bob selects three of the five balls, the probability that he selects at least one of the balls you selected when randomly selecting three of the five balls is
$$\frac{\dbinom{2}{2}\dbinom{3}{2} + \dbinom{2}{1}\dbinom{3}{2}}{\dbinom{5}{3}} = \frac{9}{10}$$
How can we correct your attempt?
Case 1:  Bob selects both of the balls you selected and one of the other three balls.  Bob either selects the two balls you selected with the first two selections, the first and third selections, or the last two selections. Thus, the probability that Bob selects exactly one of your balls is
$$\frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{3}{3} + \frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3}$$
Case 2:  Bob selects exactly one of the two balls you selected and two of the other three balls.  Bob either selects one of the balls you selected with his first, second, or third selection.  Thus, the probability that Bob selects exactly one of your balls is
$$\frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3}$$
Total:  Since these cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the probability that Bob selects at least one of the two balls you selected when randomly selecting three of the five balls is
$$\frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{3}{3} + \frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3} +\frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} + \frac{3}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{9}{10}$$

Good catch on the errors in my answer; thanks.  I am going to delete my answer.

What I dont understand is, the balls are distinctive, but the orders of selections shouldn't matter?

@CuriousMind  You can treat the problem without considering the order of selection, as I did in my subset approach, or by considering the order of selection, as I did in the correction of your attempt.

HINT: In how many ways can Bob pick two of mine? $\binom{2}{2}\binom{3}{1}$
In how many ways can Bob pick just one of mine?  $\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}$
